# urllib in python reading

Tags: python, urllib

I am supposed to write a function using the urllib library to open a url and then read and decode the file and return the string form. so far i have

```
def request(url):
    urllib.request.Request(url)
    #open URL
    urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    #read URL and decode the content string

    #return string form of URL content
```

I really dont know how to read and decode the information once i download it. if anyone could help me. since it reads the im assumsing you will use

```
urllib.request.read(url)
```

but i am not sure and i dont know what file will come back and how i am supposed to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from urllib import request
>>> data = request.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
```

By calling `read()` function on `request.urlopen` you will get the `source` of the url you passed.